# Link the same model twice to another model in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

It's probably a very basic problem, but I can't wrap my head around it how to solve this properly.

In my application, I've got users who have multiple addresses with different purposes. For example, a user can have an Address and an InvoiceAddress. I want to store both addresses in the same table (the Address model) and then assign them to one User.

The respective models look something like:

Address:

```
 public $belongsTo = array(
    'Address' => array(
        'className' => 'Address',
    ),
    'InvoiceAddress' => array(
        'className' => 'Address',
    ),
);
```

And the User:

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Address' => array(
        'className' => 'Address',
    ),
    'InvoiceAddress' => array(
        'className' => 'Address',
    ),
);
```

When a user would have one address, I'd add a user_id as foreign key to the Address model and be done with it. But obviously, something has to be done differently for CakePhp to be able to distinguish between the address and the invoice address.

In my mind the solution is something like adding a address_id and invoice_address_id to the User table, but I can't seem to get it working in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add in your user table the related fields then it is better to add them in the following form `address_user_id` and the `invoice_address_user_id`. Then you must have a belongsTo relation in your user model that looks like:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Address' => array(
        'className' => 'Address',
        'foreignKey' => 'address_user_id',
    ),
    'InvoiceAddress' => array(
        'className' => 'Address',
        'foreignKey' => 'invoice_address_user_id',
    ),
);
```

So when you execute the following command `$this->User->find('all');` the result will be

```
$result = array(0 => 
                array('User' => array(...),
                      'Address' => array(...), // it will bring only one address row
                      'InvoiceAddress' => array(...) // it will bring only one address row
                ),
                1 => ...
                2 => ...
          );
```

Then in your address Model the relationships you must add are:

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'address_user_id',
    ),
    'InvoiceUser' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'invoice_address_user_id',
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! This was the correct solution indeed. Semantically it feels a bit awkward that users do now belong to an address instead of the other way around, but I'm probably just interpreting the different possible relationships too literally.